# How can I return a list of Keys if the Values meet a condition in Spark SQL (version <= 2.4)?)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql, key-value

In Spark SQL (version <=2.4), I have a column with a Map that looks like this:

```
{"'12'": "False", "'18'": "False", "'9'": "True", "'586'": "True", "'4345'": "False", "'564'": "True", "'555'": "True", "'1'": "False"}
```

I would like to return only the Keys with `Value = "True"`. For example I would like to return:
`[9, 586, 564, 555]`.

I would like to avoid heavy string manipulations if possible due to issues during production of the query.

###Updating with answer in Spark-SQL:

```
select 
  collect_list(keys)
from (
  select
    keys
  from my_table
  lateral view explode(my_column_with_map) f as keys, values
  where values="True"
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to use explode on the map, remove the `False` values and then use `group by` and `collect_list` to form the array you desire.

In scala it could be written like this:

```scala
// generating data
val m = Map(12 -> false, 18 -> false, 9 -> true, 586 -> true, 4345 -> false,
            564 -> true, 555 -> true, 1 -> false)
val df = Seq(0, m).toDF("id", "my_map")

// and filtering out the false values
df.select('id, explode('my_map))
  .where('value) // or where('value === "True") if you deal with strings
  .groupBy('id)
  .agg(collect_list('key) as "my_seq")
  .show(false)
```

which yields:

```
+---+------------------+
|id |my_seq            |
+---+------------------+
|0  |[555, 9, 586, 564]|
+---+------------------+
```

Comment: also added the answer above in case someone needs it in Spark SQL

Comment: You're welcome. But if you have another answer, do not put it in the question. Create a second answer instead, even if you answer your own question. It'll be clearer for people who visit this post ;)